# Count numbers in scientific notation (E-notation)

Tags: postgresql, string, like, regex

I'm trying to check if a part number field has scientific notation values and came up with this simple solution:

```
SELECT count(*) as overall,
       count(*) filter (where partnumber ilike '%E+%') as matches
FROM   mytable
WHERE  partnumber ilike '%E+%';
```

Some of these strings are not scientific number. For example:

```
WS-X4748-UPOE+E=
```

How can I identify scientific numbers?

I tried this:

```
WHERE partnumber ilike '[0-9]%E+%[0-9]'
```

But it didn't seem to work.

Comment: `like` or `ilike` don't support regular expressions. You need to use `~` or `~*` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS overall
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE partnumber ~* '^[-+]?\d*\.?\d+e[-+]?\d+$') AS matches
FROM mytable
-- WHERE .. -- no outer WHERE
```

`~*` is the case-insensitive regular expression match operator.

The pattern`'^[-+]?\d*\.?\d+e[-+]?\d+$'` only applies to numbers in E-notation (without blanks).

Details in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).